# Magento 2 Create custom export entity type

Tags: magento2, csv, export

I want to create custom export CSV entity type in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom export entity type using below code

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/export.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="customtype" label="Learning Courses Export" model="Vendor\Extension\Model\Export\Courses"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/Model/Export/Courses.php

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Export;


class Courses extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity
{
    
    const COLUMN_TYPE = 'customtype';
    const COLUMN_MODEL = 'model';
    const COLUMN_PROD_IDS = 'product_ids';

    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        self::COLUMN_TYPE,
        self::COLUMN_MODEL,
        self::COLUMN_PROD_IDS,
    ];

    public function export()
    {
        // Code For Export
    }

    public function exportItem($item)
    {
        // TODO: Implement exportItem() method.
    }

    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return  'customtype';
    }

    protected function _getHeaderColumns()
    {
        return $this->_permanentAttributes;
    }

    protected function _getEntityCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Implement _getEntityCollection() method.
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/10029755?key=7e38b1047d2428899e82a8cb6a823073 showing this but not showing filed

Comment: Please check my new question  :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/340530/85907

Comment: okay @MohitPatel

Comment: Please help me i am stuck on that. @SanjayShiyal